# Can't convert ListBox.ObjectCollection to a (typed) array

Tags: c#, string, collections, arrays, listbox

I want to convert the items to a String array or the type that I used to fill the ListBox.DataSource. The type has overridden ToString() but I can't seems to get it converted, not even to String[].

```
String[] a = (String[])ListBox1.Items;
Contacts[] b = (Contacts[])ListBox1.Items;
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
string[] a = ListBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Of course, if all you plan to do with `a` is iterate over it, you don't have to call ToArray(). You can directly use the `IEnumerable<string>` returned from `Cast<string>()`, e.g.:

```
foreach (var s in ListBox1.Items.Cast<string>()) {
    do_something_with(s);
}
```

Or, if you have some way to convert strings to Contacts, you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Contacts> c = ListBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Select(s => StringToContact(s));
```

Comment: I only had to convert it to pass it as a parameter to a method. It only accepted String[] or Contact[].
Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `Cast` method doesn't seem to be available anymore. I came up with an other solution :

```
String[] array = new String[ListBox.Items.Count]
ListBox.Items.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

The `CopyTo` method takes an existing array and insert the items at the given index and forward.

I don't know if this is very efficient, but its consistent and easy to write.

Comment: to get to .Cast<>(), you need to add "using System.Linq;"