# Passing listbox to another listbox in other form

Tags: c#, winforms

I know there is a lot of similar questions like this, but I have tried everthing and it's still not working. So I have one form where you're choosing some groceries. They have been added to listbox (bill) in that form and total sum of groceries is calculeted and shown in label. By clicking on button *continue* Form1 is opening where is another listbox callled bill. I want on that form to be displayed groceries from form2 and total price. So this is my code

**Form2:**

```
private void Foodanddrink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 frm = new Form1(total3.text,bill.Items);
            frm.ShowDialog();  
        }
```

**Form1**

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public Form1(String total, ListBox.ObjectCollection items)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bill.Items.AddRange(items);
            total2.Text = total;
        }
```

**NOTE:** Sometimes I just need this Form1 to call without passing listbox from Form2.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: Form2**

```
   private void NormalProjectionFamily_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pricelabel.Visible = true;
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("REgular projection");
            lvi.SubItems.Add("4KM");
            bill.Items.Add(lvi);
            totalbill = totalbill + NormalFamily;
            total3.Text = Convert.ToString(totalbill);
        }

        private void ThreeDProjectionFamily_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pricelabel.Visible = true;
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("3D Projection");
            lvi.SubItems.Add("5KM");
            bill.Items.Add(lvi);
            totalbill = totalbill + ThreeDFamily;
            total3.Text = Convert.ToString(totalbill);
        }

        private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (bill.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;


            string currentprice = bill.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text.ToString();
            double currentpricedoub = Convert.ToDouble(currentprice.Split('K')[0]);
            totalbill = totalbill - currentpricedoub;
            total3.Text = Convert.ToString(totalbill);


            try
            {
                while (bill.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    bill.Items.Remove(bill.SelectedItems[0]);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void Foodanddrink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 frm = new Form1(total3.Text,bill.Items);
            frm.ShowDialog();


        }
```

If I try to pass just total price it works perfectly but if I add the list items I have errors like: **cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]'**

or **Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'**

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Sorry... total price works..but items from Listbox (bill) in Form2 aren't displayed in Listbox (bill) in Form1

Comment: Your code works for me just fine. Could you clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: Try adding an item manually, before and after the `AddRange`. What is the number of items?

Comment: If I try to pass just total price it works perfectly but if I add the list items I have errors like: **cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]'**  or  **Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'**

Comment: Fundamentally, your problem is that you shouldn't be passing bits of UI between forms, you should be passing a *data model*. Your UI in `Form2` should have an item control that is *bound* to an object that represents your data and that object should be what's passed around. But that's a much broader issue.

Comment: I have updated my code so you can see in which way I am adding items to bill

Comment: @Loola: Okay, so that error message is telling you what is wrong and you should include the exception *in your question*. [ListBox.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) is an `ObjectCollection` and [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx) expects to be passed an array. An `ObjectCollection` is not an array. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599125/cant-convert-listbox-objectcollection-to-a-typed-array) for some help with that.